# Flutter - WebView error with href links inside html page

Tags: android, html, flutter, dart, webview

I'm displaying html files with WebView ( [web_view_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus) ) in a WebViewPlus widget. In the html files there are links in `<a>` tags that navigate to the matching position in the same html file:

`<a href="#01">Chapter 1</a>`

`<h2><a name="01"></a>Chapter 1</h2>`

When I press the links I get errors and I'm not being navigated at the link,  but only on Android. In iOS works fine:

error:  `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/html;charset=utf-8`

full error:

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.leitourgika">
    
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="leitourgika"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't understand why this error only appears on Adnroid. How can I fix this? Can anybody help?

NOTE: I can't change the HTML files manually one-by-one because they are too many.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin.
Using your HTML example, it works both on Android and iOS, using the `initialFile` or the `initialData` InAppWebView property!

For example, using the latest version [5.0.5+3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.0.5+3) of the plugin and using the `initialFile` property:

```dart
child: InAppWebView(
  initialFile: "assets/index.html",
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true
    )
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {

  },
),
```

where `assets/index.html` is a file inside the `assets` folder of your app.
The file `index.html` is very simple:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <a href="#01">Chapter 1</a>
    <div style="height: 2000px"></div>
    <h2><a name="01"></a>Chapter 1</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, you need to add it into your `pubspec.yml` file:

```yaml
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/index.html
```

Instead, using the HTML string directly with the `initialData` property:

```dart
child: InAppWebView(
  initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
    data: """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <a href="#01">Chapter 1</a>
    <div style="height: 2000px"></div>
    <h2><a name="01"></a>Chapter 1</h2>
</body>
</html>
    """
  ),
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true
    )
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {

  },
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I had already found a dirty way to navigate manually to the specific <a> element using javascript. I will try to use InAppWebView. Thank you very much.